# Trap command from C program?

Tags: c, shell, bash-trap

I'd like to run a `trap '' 2` command from a C program to prevent `ctrl-c` when the `a.out` is run.

```
#define TRAP "trap '' 2"

int     main()
{
    system(TRAP);

    ...
}
```

I can get it to work from a `.sh` file that also runs the program but I'd like everything to be in one `.c` file.

```
trap '' 2
cd /Users/me
./a.out
```

I then tried to make another `.c` file that runs the script then launch the first `a.out` as I thought that it was a timing issue the first time without success either...

How can I get it to work within a single `a.out` or is that even possible?

Comment: The `trap` command is built into the shell itself, and only affects the currently running shell, and no other process. If you want to prevent `Ctrl-C` from breaking your program (usually a bad idea) then look into *signals* and `SIGBREAK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trap '' INT` ignores `SIGINT`. Ignore dispositions are inherited to child processes, so:

```
trap '' 2
cd /Users/me
./a.out
```

ignores `SIGINT` for what follows, but it can't work up the process hierarchy.

Fortunately it's not super difficult to ignore `SIGINT` from C.

```
#include <signal.h>
int main()
{
   //....
   signal(SIGINT,SIG_IGN); // `trap '' INT` in C
   //^should never fail unless the args are buggy
   //...
}
```